# is head light bulb a low beam because the reflector inside the headlight assembly is angled downward toward the road? or there's more to it?

Tags: honda, toyota

What makes a low beam bulb a low beam? I've heard that you can fit a high beam bulb inside a low beam beam socket, but now vice versa. So is all about the position of the reflector?

Answer (score 2):

There are single filament bulbs and double filament bulbs.

Double filament bulbs use the reflector with the positioning of the filaments to control the position of the beam.

Single filament bulbs often have two headlights on each side - one for low and the other for high. Some cars will turn off the low when going to high while others have both on at the same time for high.

Both types of bulb have pins or tags to make sure the filaments are correctly positioned, so the correct one has to be fitted.

Answer (score 1):

Then there are newer Subaru headlights (and likely other manufacturers as well who probably do the same thing with LED headlights) which have a single lighting element (multiple LEDs) that are always on, and there's a little metal flap that flips up to block part of the light when only low-beam is running.  See https://youtu.be/Qkfq471tmKM?t=1202 for how it works.